# Rails: localhost works, but internal IP refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I write a simple Rails web application.
When I type "http://localhost:3000/events/7.json" in URL, it works.

But when I type "http://192.168.56.73:3000/events/7.json" it shows "connection refused".

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails only listens to localhost (127.0.0.1) by default. You'll need to specify what IP you want the rails server to listen to if you want it be available on something other than localhost.

`rails server --binding 0.0.0.0`

or

`rails server --binding 192.168.56.73` in your case.

This is what I could find on how to do it with rails. Normally with other ruby servers it's `-h 0.0.0.0`.